# Python script will not write to database when launching from Spring Boot

Tags: python, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying to create a website where I can run a python script after clicking on a button. I'm using spring boot for the server and MySQL for the database. Everything works, including the python script, but when I launch it from within Spring the script will not write to the database. I know the script runs since it uses selenium and it's not in headless mode. MySQL Workbench says there's a new connection to the DB every time I run the script through Spring.

I'm using mysql-connector-python for python and Hibernate for Spring.

This is the part of the script responsible of writing to the database.

EDIT: I should mention I'm starting the script using ProcessBuilder in the controller in Spring.

```
for course_offered in courses_offered.values():
    cur.execute(ADD_COURSE_QUERY, (course_offered[0], course_offered[1], course_offered[2], course_offered[3]))
for semester, courses in courses_by_semester.items():
    if len(courses) >= 1:
        for course in courses:
            cur.execute(ADD_COURSE_OFFERING_QUERY, (course[0], course[1], semester))
cnx.commit()
cur.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Why would you run a Python script from Spring Boot to modify a database? It would be simpler to just do that directly from spring boot. That fact you mention your script also uses Selenium and 'not in headless mode', sounds like additional complications. In any case, without a [mre] we cannot help you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the script is a scraper and I find it easier to scrape in Python than Java. Eventually it will be a scheduled job. Selenium will be in headless mode when I'm done developing this, but it's my best way right now to tell if the script runs at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I guess since sub processes have their I/O set to the parent, you have to reset it. I had to use ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() before starting the process and everything worked fine. It's easier to debug scripts this way too since the script can now print to console.